# collision detection not all sides of rectangle will correctly collide

Tags: c#, winforms

The program has a ball, bat and rectangle. I have managed to get the ball to correctly collide with the bat, that's fine. The problem is with the rectangle.

With the rectangle from what I have attempted so far it does detect collisions from the top side and left side, but I am struggling to get the same affect with the bottom and right side.

Any pointers as to where I am going wrong I would much appreciate. I have included code below for clarity. Also, when the ball does collide correctly, it rebounds towards the top left.

```
    Graphics paper;
    SolidBrush brush;
    private Random randomNum;
    Rectangle ball, bat, brick;
    int x, y, yChange, xChange, batX;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        paper = picBox.CreateGraphics();
        randomNum = new Random();           
        bat = new Rectangle();
        brick = new Rectangle();            
    }       

    private void MoveBall()
    {
        timer1.Interval = randomNum.Next(80, 200);
        timer1.Enabled = true;

        x = x + xChange;
        y = y + yChange;
        if (x >= picBox.Width)
            xChange = -xChange;

        if (y >= picBox.Height)
            yChange = -yChange;

        if (x <= 0)
            xChange = -xChange;

        if (y <= 0)
            yChange = -yChange;
    }

    private void DrawBall()
    {
        brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
        ball = new Rectangle(x, y, 14, 14);
        paper.FillEllipse(brush, ball);
    }

    private void DrawBat()
    {
        int batXpos, batYpos;
        batXpos = batX - 25; batYpos = picBox.Height - 40;
        bat = new Rectangle(batXpos, batYpos, 100, 20);
        brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);
        paper.FillRectangle(brush, bat);
    }

    private void DrawBricks()
    {
        brick = new Rectangle(200, 100, 100, 50);
        brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Pink);
        paper.FillRectangle(brush, brick);
    }

    private void CheckCollision()
    {
        int ballTop, ballRight, ballDown, ballLeft;
        ballTop = ball.Y + 7; ballDown = ball.Y + 14 + (ball.X + 7);            //THESE WERE JUST SOME ATTEMPTS TO GET
        ballRight = ball.X + 14 + (ball.Y + 7); ballLeft = ball.Y + 7;          //LOCATION OF THE BALL AND BRICK X AND Y
                                                                                //COORDS BUT STILL HAD PROBLEMS
        int brickTL, brickTR, brickBL, brickBR;
        brickTL = brick.X; brickTR = brick.X + 100;
        brickBL = brick.Y + 50; brickBR = brick.X + 100 + (brick.Y + 50);


        if (ball.IntersectsWith(bat))                          //NO PROBLEMS HERE                 
        {
            yChange = -10;

        }

        if (ball.IntersectsWith(brick))                                     //WORKS FINE FOR DETECTION ON THE TOP SIDE
        {
            xChange = -5;
        }

        if (ball.IntersectsWith(brick))                                         //WORKS FINE FOR THE RIGHT SIDE
        {
            yChange = -5;
        }

        if ((ballTop >= brickBR) && (x < picBox.Width))
        {
            yChange = 5;
        }
    }                

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Interval = randomNum.Next(80, 200);
        timer1.Enabled = true;

        x = randomNum.Next(5, picBox.Width);
        y = randomNum.Next(5, picBox.Height);
        xChange = randomNum.Next(5, 15);
        yChange = randomNum.Next(5, 15);           

    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        paper.Clear(Color.Gray);         

        DrawBall();
        MoveBall();
        DrawBat();
        CheckCollision();
        DrawBricks();
    }

    private void picBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        batX = e.X;
    }
```

Comment: Please avoid ALL CAPS. it looks like you're yelling at people.

Comment: sorry for future reference keep it in mind thanks

Comment: ok thanks new to the site sorry

Answer (score 0):

I imagine your conditionals are getting hit just fine.. but you are not actually affecting the ball movement.

When the ball is moving `up` it will have a negative delta, and when moving `left` will also have a negative delta.

When a collision is detected you need to reverse the sign of the delta.. like:

`xChange *= -1;` and `yChange *= -1;`

Comment: that sends the ball back and forth continuously??

Comment: As I can not see your changes I don't know what `that` is.